# Calculating network speed on macOS using Swift returns wrong values

Tags: swift, networking

I am trying to calculate the download and upload speed for my network adapter using Swift.
The code seems to work, however, the values are off compared to speed tests.

Here is my code:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
    var timer: Timer?
    var old: Int64 = 0
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    private func getBytesInfo(_ pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) -> (upload: Int64, download: Int64)?
    {
        guard pointer.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) else { return nil }
            
        let data: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>? = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
        return (upload: Int64(data?.pointee.ifi_obytes ?? 0), download: Int64(data?.pointee.ifi_ibytes ?? 0))
    }

    @objc fileprivate func refresh()
    {
        var interfaceAddresses: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil
        guard getifaddrs(&interfaceAddresses) == 0 else { return }
        
        var pointer = interfaceAddresses
        
        while pointer != nil
        {
            defer { pointer = pointer?.pointee.ifa_next }
            
            if String(cString: pointer!.pointee.ifa_name) != "en1" // Please adjust and use your primary network adapter.
            {
                continue
            }
            
            if let info = getBytesInfo(pointer!)
            {
                if Double(info.download) - Double(self.old) > 0.0
                {
                    let value = UInt64(info.download - self.old)
                    
                    Swift.print(Double(value) / 1024.0 / 1024.0) // MB/s
                    Swift.print(Double(value * 8) / 1000.0 / 1000.0) // Mb/s
                    Swift.print()
                }
                
                self.old = Int64(info.download)
            }
        }
        
        freeifaddrs(interfaceAddresses)
    }
}
```

Here is the output (I have tested this multiple times, there are no other processes running that would explain such a big difference):

[image: Output]

I am testing on macOS Monterey. I have tested two machines, both show the same behaviour.
Is my code wrong?
I am not using any VPN. I have checked both Wi-Fi and Ethernet.

Comment: you should never use a timer to measure elapsed time

Comment: This is a very basic example. In my production code, I am not using hard coded values and measure the time with timestamps. It is not 1.0 seconds, it is like 0.997, but even this does not explain such a huge difference. P.S. What is an alternative to Timer?